# What mean Malakos in 1 Cor. 6:9

Tags: 1-corinthians

În 1Cor. 6:9, can the term malakos refer to a person who practices masturbation? If so, what evidence are there to support this theory. If not, what word was used by greeks to describe masturbation (with evidence)?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: The etymology of the word is well documented (see, for example, [Strong 3120](https://biblehub.com/greek/3120.htm)) and Thayer's comments. There is no evidence of the meaning you suggest.

Comment: Thomas Aquinas, no mean mind, interpreted "effeminate" here to refer to such, I believe. It could also refer to the 'passive' (i.e. the more effeminate) partner in a homosexual relationship and the following word those who actually "bed" them, since it means "bedders of males."

Answer (score 1):

@florentin constantin.---You can easily find answers to this question by reading the NET Bible translation notes. 
The NET on " μαλακός " :

> tn This term is sometimes rendered “effeminate,” although in
>   contemporary English usage such a translation could be taken to refer
>   to demeanor rather than behavior. BDAG 613 s.v. μαλακός 2 has “pert.
>   to being passive in a same-sex relationship, effeminate esp. of
>   catamites, of men and boys who are sodomized by other males in such a
>   relationship.” L&N 88.281 states, “the passive male partner in
>   homosexual intercourse—‘homosexual.’ … As in Greek, a number of other
>   languages also have entirely distinct terms for the active and passive
>   roles in homosexual intercourse.” See also the discussion in G. D.
>   Fee, First Corinthians (NICNT), 243–44. A number of modern
>   translations have adopted the phrase “male prostitutes” for μαλακοί in
>   1 Cor 6:9 (NIV, NRSV, NLT) but this could be misunderstood by the
>   modern reader to mean “males who sell their services to women,” while
>   the term in question appears, at least in context, to relate to
>   homosexual activity between males. Furthermore, it is far from certain
>   that prostitution as commonly understood (the selling of sexual
>   favors) is specified here, as opposed to a consensual relationship.
>   Thus the translation “passive homosexual partners” has been used here.
>
> Biblical Studies Press, The NET Bible First Edition; Bible. English.
>   NET Bible.; The NET Bible (Biblical Studies Press, 2005).

The NET on " ἀρσενοκοίτης ":

> On this term BDAG 135 s.v. ἀρσενοκοίτης states, “a male who engages in
>   sexual activity w. a pers. of his own sex, pederast 1 Cor 6:9 … of one
>   who assumes the dominant role in same-sex activity, opp. μαλακός … 1
>   Ti 1:10; Pol 5:3. Cp. Ro 1:27.” L&N 88.280 states, “a male partner in
>   homosexual intercourse—‘homosexual.’ … It is possible that
>   ἀρσενοκοίτης in certain contexts refers to the active male partner in
>   homosexual intercourse in contrast with μαλακός, the passive male
>   partner.” Since there is a distinction in contemporary usage between
>   sexual
>
> Biblical Studies Press, The NET Bible First Edition; Bible. English.
>   NET Bible.; The NET Bible (Biblical Studies Press, 2005).